# Objects turns black on texturing viewport

Tags: texturing

Does anyone knows how to solve object or model blackout. It happens whenever I click on the any button that is related to texturing, e.g. look Dev, render preview button, uv shading like the one in the picture. Please, guys help me out! It has been causing me to stand down against BLENDER. Can't go on without my textures showing what's proper[image]

Comment: Why are you adding the BDSF output to a displacement node? It's not meant to be there.

Comment: Okay. I will change that, I did according to the tutorial I watched, actually what he made was quiet unbelievable. But that's not the cause for the black color. Cos before I touched anything on the port the color was still black

Comment: Okay. I will change that, I did according to the tutorial I watched, actually what he made was quiet unbelievable. But that's not the cause for the black color. Cos before I touched anything on the port the color was still black